# How do I resolve the error "don't know how to turn this value into a node" for a Vue 3 app using babel-plugin-istanbul extending .vue

Tags: babeljs, cypress, vuejs3, istanbul, cypress-code-coverage

My ultimate goal is to get e2e and unit code coverage for my Vue 3 app using Cypress in my CI/CD pipelines.

However, when using the following configuration in my `babel.config.js` I get a flood of repeated error messages that read `don't know how to turn this value into a node at transformFile.next (<anonymous>)` **for each Vue file in my app that uses `<script setup>`.**

babel.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['babel-plugin-istanbul', {
      extension: ['.js', '.vue']
    }]
  ],
};
```

package.json

```js
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-istanbul": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
```

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
</script>
```

My concern is that the plugin doesn't know how to handle Vue 3's script setup syntax.
Sadly, the only how-to guides I can find online are for Vue 2 or React apps.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#Using-NYC

https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2020/07/20/code-coverage-vue-cypress/

---

**So my question is: what can I do to get my app to transpile while using `babel-plugin-istanbul` and `script setup`?**

---

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Create a new Vue 3 app with vue-cli-service
2. Install `babel-plugin-istanbul` in your dev dependencies
3. Configure your `babel.config.js` as shown above
4. Convert your App.vue to use `<script setup>`
5. Run `npm run serve`

Expected behavior:
The app transpiles with no errors

Actual behavior:
Transpilation failure with `don't know how to turn this value into a node` errors for App.vue.

Comment: Seeing the same issue here with vue-cli 5.0.4

Answer (score 2):

The resolve is to use `istanbul` in the babel config (as given in Cypress docs).

The cause isn't apparent, without `<script setup>` the full name `babel-plugin-istanbul` works ok.

```js
  plugins: [
    ['istanbul', {
      extension: ['.js', '.vue']
    }]
  ],
```

Comment: Gave this a shot, but it still fails to transpile and pumps out the same errors.

Comment: It worked when I tested it. What do you have in the project that's not shown above? Or is there a repo?

Comment: Using a brand new Vue 3 app. Only alteration I made was with App.vue, which I just added above to the question. However, these errors only happen after a fresh install of the node_modules. So if I were to kill the app and reboot it with `npm run serve` the errors disappear. This is fine for local development, but I need to get this working in CI/CD without having to anticipate an initial failure since node_modules are always freshly installed in a pipeline.

Comment: I also used a fresh Vue 3, and didn't get the error, at least not with `plugins: [ ['istanbul', ...`

Comment: The only material difference, the CLI gave me `"@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.12",` (plus same ver for plugins). That may be due to my global being slightly out of date.

Comment: Recorded a loom video to better show what I'm experiencing on my end: https://www.loom.com/share/d6e6707bba63430384172b97368d40bf

Answer (score 1):

I am solving same problem and I can point out two things:

1. The problem is in babel.config.js file especially with `.vue` extension, when you remove it works, but for me it instrument all files.
2. I have a feeling another problem is with CLI versions plugins. I don't have problem to run the cypress code coverage plugin with older packages.

Answer (score 0):

If add extension:['.vue'] in bable.config.js configuration, getting below error.

src/pages/somefile.vue?vue&type=script&setup=true&lang=js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: src/pages/somefile.vue: don't know how to turn this value into a node

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33309326)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this as well. It turned out to be a bug in the istanbul-lib-instrument package, which was fixed in this PR: https://github.com/istanbuljs/istanbuljs/pull/662

If you upgrade your installed copy of istanbul-lib-instrument to 5.2.1 (i.e., `npm update istanbul-lib-instrument`) the issue should go away.

Comment: I updated it but still get the error, but it gone when I remove .vue in bable config